# How to create a MySQL query that returns the replies to a given user's comments

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a page that displays all replies to first tier comments of the active user. Here is an example DB table similar to the one I have...

| commentid | postid | commid | username | userid | commtext |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 52 | 100 | 0 | user1 | 1 | first |
| 53 | 100 | 52 | user2 | 2 | second |
| 54 | 100 | 52 | user1 | 1 | third |

"commentid" is the comment's unique id, "postid" is the id of the post it was on, "commid" gives the number of the comment that it was a response to ("0" indicates it is on the first tier), and so on...

If I am logged in as "user1" and I do the following...

```
$ra = $DB->Execute('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE userid = '.$DB->qstr($id).' ORDER BY commentid DESC')
```

...it will return comments #52 and #54. Simple enough.

I am having an issue creating a request to the DB that will output a list that gives me #53 (which was a reply to user1's comment). If possible, I do not want to include #54 which was written by the active user him/herself.

What would be a good way to construct this query?

Comment: Does something like this work `'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commid = 52 AND  userid != '.$DB->qstr($id).' ORDER BY commentid DESC'`?

Comment: Something like that would be on the right track, but instead of saying "commid = 52", I would need to implement some way to lookup that number based on the userid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to retrieve the first level replies (ignoring those from the initial user), you can `JOIN` comments to itself to find the replies, filtering out those with the same `userid`:

```sql
SELECT rep.*
FROM comments rep
JOIN comments cmt
WHERE rep.commid = cmt.commentid
  AND cmt.userid = 1
  AND rep.userid != 1
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
commentid   postid  commid  username    userid  commtext
53          100     52      user2       2       second
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM1XXAYTYpaM9cm3XfdPB5/0)